# Assembly code help (creating new file)

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

I'm new in assembly. I have to do a program that copies the data of an input file to an out put file. but this output file has to be created.

The problem is that I cannot create this file which seems to be so straight forward.

the Code i am using is

```
.model tiny
.data

outputfile db "newfile.txt",0   
outhandle dw ?  
        .code
.stack
    cseg segment 'code'
assume cs:cseg, ds:cseg
org 100h
start:
create_a_file:
 mov dx, offset outputfile
 mov cx, 0
 mov ah, 3Ch
 int 21h
 mov outhandle, ax
jc error_routine
mov ah, 3Eh
 mov bx, outhandle
 int 21h

error_routine:
mov ax, 4c00h
 int 21h
 cseg ends
end start
```

I see the new file nowhere.Even when I specify the exact root folder like "c:..."
I cant figure out what is going wrong.
Any help is appriciated, Thanx
 PS: Im using windows XP 32-bit. and TASM (portable)

Comment: I do wish people would stop bothering with 8086 asm.  It's pretty much obsolete on modern computers, esp 64-bit ones; i wouldn't even be able to run this without firing up a VM.

Comment: @cHao: what's wrong with this? I think it's a great way of lerning the internals of a CPU and also very interesting. Useless, perhaps, but interesting and challenging :)

Comment: @BlackBear: Oh, i have no problem with assembly language.  Love the stuff, actually.  :)  But 16-bit code is going the way of the dinosaur -- these days, it's only useful for boot loaders and such.  And there's so much to unlearn when someone finally realizes that.  These days, x86 (32-bit) ought to be the baseline.

Comment: @cHao: True, the only problem is that there aren't interrupts in 32 bits code, they make the life much simpler than using WriteFile ;)

Comment: @cHao - "Going the way of the dinosaur" was the mastodon's last line, 16-bit code was nice and dead for over 10 years.  Strong comeback this year though, think it has something to do with the educational system in India.  Last year it was Turbo C.  Using comments in asm code is apparently not strongly encouraged.  I can't bother to dig up Ralph's list again.  But please help to vote this question closed.

Comment: @BlackBear: Life *might* be easier.  (Highly debatable; `mov ah, 3ch; int 21h` isn't nearly as obvious as `call WriteFileA` unless you have the API memorized.)  But if 32-bit code can't even use the API the same way, that means pretty much the whole program will need a rewrite in order to run unemulated on a modern CPU.  Better to get with the times *before* you have to go through all that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your intention is to create a .COM program, simplify the source code to this:

```
cseg segment 'code'
    assume cs:cseg, ds:cseg, es:cseg, ss:cseg
    org 100h
start:

create_a_file:
    mov dx, offset outputfile
    mov cx, 0
    mov ah, 3Ch
    int 21h
    mov outhandle, ax
    jc  error_routine

    mov ah, 3Eh
    mov bx, outhandle
    int 21h

error_routine:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h

outputfile db "newfile.txt",0   
outhandle dw ?  

cseg ends

end start
```

Compile the program as `tasm.exe myprog.asm` and link it as `tlink.exe /t myprog.obj`. You should get `myprog.com` and it should create `NEWFILE.TXT` just fine.

Comment: Thank your for your answers,
I used alex's answer and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Check your tasm/bin folder. Your "newfile.txt" may be there

Comment: It is unlikely that the above program as-is could produce a file because it would only compile into .EXE. Unlinke .COMs, .EXE's have to set up their `DS` and `ES` registers, while the above code doesn't do that and proceeds to calling DOS with a bad filename string address, not address of `outputfile`.